# How to get the content of a CKEditor within a WebView

Tags: javafx, ckeditor, javafx-8

In JavaFX 8, when there is a Stage that contains a WebView which shows a CKEditor in it, how can I get the content I wrote there to the Java application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem with the following Code which executes a Call to the CKEDITOR API using the `WebView` `WebEngine`. Object will be an instance of `String` containing the editor content.

```
   Object obj= wv.getEngine().executeScript("CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData()");
```